# Error while booting Windows 11 with Kali Linux

Tags: boot, kali-linux, windows

I had installed Windows 11 on my SSD drive. Then I shrinked the SSD drive and installed Kali Linux to it. Both Windows and linux worked well, but suddenly when I opened Windows, it gives me

> error critical process died

and when I open the linux Desktop and Menus in Linux, it didn't work. So I reinstalled Kali Linux first and then downloaded Windows 11 from internet and installed it to an USB drive, restarted my computer and pressed <kbd>F12</kbd>. It opened Windows which has two options: my SSD drive and my USB drive.

I chose the USB drive and it should install me Windows 11, but instead it gave me the error `0xc00000000e`. I tried to install Windows 10 like that, but it gave me the same error. With Kali linux it works.

What can I do?

Comment: I would suggest that most security professionals who install Kali do so either as a standalone system or as a VM. Do you really need Kali?

Comment: As above. And also would like to suggest the proper troubleshooting for the future. When chainloading from Grub to Windows fails, the first thing to do is to try to boot Windows directly. If that fails as well then you need to repair Windows by booting its installation media and using its tools for the purpose. Do NOT touch thew OS that's booting correctly, fix the one that doesn't.